# composition of measureable function with $\sqrt x$ in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I was wondering if my hypothesis is correct:
Let $X=L^2[0,1]$, $f\in X$, $g:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ definited as $g(x)=\sqrt x$

Is $f\circ g\in L^2[0,1]$ necessarily?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using the change of variable $x=\sqrt t$,
$$
\int_0^1|f(\sqrt t)|^2\,dt=2\int_0^1x\,|f(x)|^2\,dx\leq2\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx<\infty
$$
The change of variable is obvious for continuous $f$, and can be deduced for arbitrary $f$ by approximation with continuous functions and using dominated convergence.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Could you give more details regarding how to use the dominated convergence in order to get that it is correct to use the change of variable?
Say $(fn)$ is a series of continuous functions that converges in 2-norm to f. what now?